# Why is GSON not retrieving all vales from a JSON file?

Tags: java, json, eclipse, gson

I was programming a program to try to retrieve values from a JSON file by using GSON, however, I noticed that GSON wasn't able to retrieve all of my values. For example, going into debug mode in eclipse, I found out most of the values were null.

**Debug Mode:**
[Picture When Accessing Variables In Debug Mode In Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJVks.png)

**This is my JSON File:**

```
{
"shoes": [
    {
        "shoeName": "Shoe",
        "shoePrice": "120",
        "brand": "Shoe",
        "typeOfShoes": "Running",
        "style": "Cool",
        "Color": [
            "Blue",
            "Green",
            "Pink"
        ],
        "Sizes": [
            "W5/M3.5",
            "W5.5/M4"
        ],
        "Description": "The Shoe SE features sleek lines and a sheer upper that combine classic Air Max elements into a lightweight, comfortable and versatile icon. Together with its smart toe-down profile and extra lift, the shoe offers an ever-bigger expression..",
        "shipping": "0",
        "tax": "0",
        "sub-total": "0",
        "review": "4.5",
        "totalRaffles": "80",
        "isSold": "false"
    },
    {
        "shoeName": "Empty Shoe",
        "shoePrice": "0",
        "brand": "null",
        "typeOfShoes": "null",
        "style": "null",
        "Color": ["null"
        ],
        "Sizes": ["null"
        ],
        "Description": "null",
        "shipping": "0",
        "tax": "0",
        "sub-total": "0",
        "review": "0",
        "totalRaffles": "0",
        "isSold": "false"
    },
    {
        "shoeName": "Empty Shoe1",
        "shoePrice": "0",
        "brand": "null",
        "typeOfShoes": "null",
        "style": "null",
        "Color": ["null"
        ],
        "Sizes": ["null"
        ],
        "Description": "null",
        "shipping": "0",
        "tax": "0",
        "sub-total": "0",
        "review": "0",
        "totalRaffles": "0",
        "isSold": "false"
    }
]

}
```

The JSON file is structured relatively easy. There are multiple objects (shoes) which each have their own properties, such as shoeName, shoePrice, etc.

**ReadJSON.java**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.pulsebeat02.main.gui.Shoe;
import com.pulsebeat02.main.gui.windows.StartingWindow;

public class ReadJSON {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        parseJSON();

    }

    public static void parseJSON() {

        String cwd = System.getProperty("user.dir");

        File f = new File(cwd + "/shoes.json");

        String str = null;
        try {
            str = readFile(f);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        Type dataType = (new TypeToken<Shoes>() {
        }).getType();

        Shoes shoeList = gson.fromJson(str, dataType);

        List<Shoe> shoes = shoeList.getShoes();

        Shoe[] shoesFinal = new Shoe[shoes.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < shoesFinal.length; i++) {

            shoesFinal[i] = shoes.get(i);

        }

        StartingWindow.shoesInGui = shoesFinal;

        System.out.println(shoeList);
        System.out.println("Ran");

    }

    public static String readFile(File file) throws IOException {
        return new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
    }

}
```

Because there were multiple objects (shoes) in the JSON file, I had to make a class named "Shoes.java" to create a list of Shoes.

**Shoes.java**

```
import java.util.List;

import com.pulsebeat02.main.gui.Shoe;

public class Shoes {

    private List<Shoe> shoes;

    public List<Shoe> getShoes() {
        return shoes;
    }

    public void setShoes(List<Shoe> shoes) {
        this.shoes = shoes;
    }

}
```

And finally, this is my Shoe.java class that defines the Shoe object.

**Shoe.java**

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Shoe {

    public int shoePrice;
    public int shipping;
    public int tax;
    public int subtotal;
    public int totalUsers;

    public double review;

    public int totalRaffles;

    public String shoeName;
    public String style;
    public String typeOfShoes;
    public String brand;

    public Image[] images;

    public String name;
    public String description;
    public String[] colors;
    public String[] sizes;

    public boolean isSold;

    public Shoe(int shoePrice, int shipping, int tax, int subtotal, double review,

            int totalRaffles,

            String shoeName, String style, String typeOfShoes, String brand,

            Image[] images,

            String description, String[] colors, String[] sizes,

            boolean isSold) {

        this.shoePrice = shoePrice;
        this.shipping = shipping;
        this.tax = tax;
        this.subtotal = subtotal;
        this.review = review;
        this.totalRaffles = totalRaffles;
        this.sizes = sizes;
        this.shoeName = shoeName;
        this.style = style;
        this.typeOfShoes = typeOfShoes;
        this.images = images;
        this.description = description;
        this.colors = colors;
        this.isSold = isSold;
        this.brand = brand;

    }

    public Shoe(String shoePrice2, String shipping2, String tax2, String subTotal2, String review2,
            String totalRaffles2, String shoeName2, String style2, String typeOfShoes2, String brand2,
            List<String> images2, String description2, List<String> color, List<String> sizes2, String isSold2) {

        this.shoePrice = Integer.parseInt(shoePrice2);
        this.shipping = Integer.parseInt(shipping2);
        this.tax = Integer.parseInt(tax2);
        this.subtotal = Integer.parseInt(subTotal2);
        this.review = Double.parseDouble(review2);
        this.totalRaffles = Integer.parseInt(totalRaffles2);

        this.shoeName = shoeName2;
        this.style = style2;
        this.typeOfShoes = typeOfShoes2;
        this.brand = brand2;

        this.images = loadImage((String[]) images2.toArray());
        this.description = description2;
        this.colors = (String[]) color.toArray();
        this.sizes = (String[]) sizes2.toArray();
        this.isSold = Boolean.getBoolean(isSold2);

    }

    public static Shoe[] toArray(List<Shoe> list) {

        Shoe[] shoes = new Shoe[list.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

            shoes[i] = list.get(i);

        }

        return shoes;

    }

    public static Image[] loadImage(String[] imageURLs) {

        Image[] images = new Image[imageURLs.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < imageURLs.length; i++) {

            Image image = null;
            try {
                image = ImageIO.read(new URL(imageURLs[i]));
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            images[i] = image;

        }

        return images;

    }
```

Does anyone know the issue that GSON is having here making properties of the SHoe object to be null?

Comment: For the case `Description` is null, please align the case as the java field `description`. In general the field name should match the key in json.

Comment: @samabcde Ahh, I found my issue. The issue was that the variable names were not the same as the names in the JSON file. Thank you for reminding me about this. You saved me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem. For people using GSON for a JSON parser, please make sure to check the variable names and make sure they match with the variable names in the JSON files, or else they will be null. Thanks samabcde!